# Python IDE creates folder after which it has no permission to (write or read)

Tags: python, permissions, pycharm, chmod, ioerror

In a project I have a function that creates a folder when it doesn't exist yet with the os package.

Now I run into the error then when this folder is created (I run the script with the IDE pycharm) nobody has access, hence the error "IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied" occurs.

The project runs in a virtual environment, python2.7 and the function is in the gist of:

```
if not os.path.exists(folder):
   os.makedirs(folder)
```

What is causing the folder to be inaccessible? Any insights why this is occurring? If I missed any relevant information please let me know.

(changing the permission rights per folder is no solution as the folders need to be created on the fly by user input)

[image: result of folder creation]

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) you can set the permission on directory with:

```
os.makedirs(folder, mode=0o777)
```

Beware that mode is not string but octal

Comment: The documentation indicates that the default mode is 0777. Somehow, the nested folder is _not_ created with access rights for everyone..

From the docs:
_Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory. Raises an error exception if the leaf directory already exists or cannot be created. The default mode is 0777 (octal)._